# Cucumber JVM: How do I use a double as an input value?

Tags: regex, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

For a Behavior test that I'm trying to write, I require inputs that are floating point.  How do I set up my gherkin string to look for these values?

Answer (score 11):

Simple `(.+)` should work

```
Given I have a floating point 1.2345 number

@Given("^I have a floating point (.+) number$")
public void I_have_a_floating_point_number(double arg) throws Throwable { 
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

My own preference is to specify digits either side of a dot, something like...

```
@Given("^the floating point value of (\\d+.\\d+)$")
public void theFloatingPointValueOf(double arg) {
    // assert something
}
```

and as you mentioned floating point inputs plural, I might handle the multiple inputs with an outline like...

```
Scenario Outline: handling lots of floating point inputs
    Given the floating point value of <floatingPoint>
    When something happens
    Then some outcome

    Examples:
        | floatingPoint |
        | 2.0           |
        | 2.4           |
        | 5.8           |
        | 3.2           |
```

And it will run a scenario per floating point input

Answer (score 2):

I use the form

```
 @When("^We change the zone of the alert to \\(([0-9\\.]+),([0-9\\.]+)\\) with a radius of (\\d+) meters.$")
 public void we_change_the_zone_of_the_alert_to_with_a_radius_of_meters(double latitude, double longitude, int radius)
```

so `[0-9.]+` make the deal :)

Take care of the local of your cucumber. If you're using `language:fr` for example, number are using `,` for delimiter.

Comment: The language makes the difference! It's the same for language: de. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

**You should escape the float number with `(\\d+)`**

Example

```
Given I have a floating point 1.2345 number

@Given("^I have a floating point (\\d+) number$")
public void I_have_a_floating_point(double arg){

}
```

Comment: That was not the matter of the question